# AngularJs custom directive does not render after using $compile

Tags: angularjs, compilation

I'm trying to get angularjs form validation to work with a span that is added inside a directive when validation is needed. The formName and name of the form element are dynamically created and transformed in the validation string with string interpolation.

```
export class AbiFormBuilderDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public static $inject = [];
    public restrict = "E";

    templateUrl = $("#DirectiveTemplateUrls").data("abiformbuilder");

    constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService) { }

    public scope = {
        option: "=",
        name: "=",
        formName: "="
    }

    public link = (scope: IAbiFormBuilderDirectiveScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs) => {
        scope.uniqueName = `option_${scope.option.id}`;
        const content = `<span class="text-danger" ng-if="${scope.formName}.${scope.uniqueName}.$error.required">error</span>`;
        this.$compile(element.append(content))(scope);
    }

    public static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($compile) => {
            return new AbiFormBuilderDirective($compile);
        };
        directive.$inject = ["$compile"];
        return directive;
    }
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="{{uniqueName}}" name="{{uniqueName}}" ng-model="value" class="form-control" placeholder="{{option.name}}" required />
```

I want to achieve a dynamic form control that adds an error span as soon as the input is required. When I debug I see the input rendering with its span but then it disappears. If I remove the $compile then I see the control but my validation is always visible.

Can somebody guide me in the right direction?

Comment: can u verify that formName and option are already defined while link is runnunig?

Comment: Yes they are giving back the correct values.

Comment: What is the usage of your directive? I don't see how you use it on your input element.